# how to set direction to a Polyline on google-map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

am using this code to get URL direction from google

```
String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

// Destination of route
String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

// Sensor enabled
String sensor = "sensor=false";

// Building the parameters to the web service
String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

// Output format
String output = "json";

// Building the url to the web service
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

return url;
```

Here it draws a line considering google maps directions.
Is there a way i can Provide the direction as well (in degrees from north) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the bearing between two positions, knowing their longitude and latitude, so for each step of your direction object, calculate the bearing as shown on this link to know the direction : 
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html